# Why do we have to separate State/Mutation/Action?

Tags: vuex

I understand different roles among Action/Mutation/State in Vuex, and also I know that I can just directly call Mutation or State without going thru previous stages.

However, why does the architect of Vuex plan them this way?

I was looking for an answer for this on the official website,
but it was not that possible.

Is there anyone who can give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea here is separate different structures. It's seems logical to store different structures in different files. And it's easy to maintane and debug. Plus it's nice to have short and clear files rather than big one.